# QuarkusComponentTest using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, quarkus-testing

I am trying to use QuarkusComponentTest in kotlin as in the java quarkus [documentation](https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-component-test/):

**Charlie class**

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
class Charlie
```

**Foo class:**

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped

@ApplicationScoped
class Foo(private val charlie: Charlie)
```

**Unit test:**

```
@QuarkusComponentTest
internal class FooTest {

    @Inject
    lateinit var foo: Foo

    @InjectMock
    lateinit var charlieMock: Charlie

    @Test
    fun testPing() {
        println("ping")
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Normal scoped beans must declare a non-private constructor with no parameters: CLASS bean [types=[com.test.Foo, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.test.Foo]

at io.quarkus.arc.processor.Beans.validateBean(Beans.java:767)
at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanInfo.validate(BeanInfo.java:605)
at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.validateBeans(BeanDeployment.java:1559)
at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.validate(BeanDeployment.java:482)
at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.validate(BeanProcessor.java:167)
```

am I missing something here?